# PHP sessions to go to user specific page

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I am trying to make a page where a user logs in and they are taken to a personalized page. What I am having problems with is, while the user is still logged in, if they type in the generic url, that they are still logged in and their personalized page is viewable. (Similar to when you are logged into Facebook and it goes straight to your feed if you type in www.facebook.com) I tried using sessions for this, but am having no luck.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) != true) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
</html>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Welcome</h1><br>


 If you have an existing account, log in here:<br>
    <form name="loginForm" action="test.php" method="get">
        User name: <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    Otherwise, if you'd like to create an account, please fill out the following form:<br>
    <form name="createAccountForm" action="test.php" method="get">
        User name: <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="create" value="true">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) == true) {
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{
  header('location:test.php?redirect='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}

// personalized page code
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php probably outputting before header too.

Comment: `if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) != true)` doesn't work that way, same for `if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) == true)`

Comment: You cannot start a session `session_start();` after you have sent stuff to the output buffer. Move the `session_start();` to after the FIRST `<?php`

Comment: take it up with the answer you've been given below. Good luck with it, you'll need to do quite a few modifications to it in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:: A solution first for your own existing code.  should work fine.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])) {

if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{
  header('location:test.php?redirect='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}

// personalized page code
} else {

?>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
</html>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Welcome</h1><br>


 If you have an existing account, log in here:<br>
    <form name="loginForm" action="test.php" method="get">
        User name: <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    Otherwise, if you'd like to create an account, please fill out the following form:<br>
    <form name="createAccountForm" action="test.php" method="get">
        User name: <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="create" value="true">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is a login solution of my own (stripped out a bit to be generic) it also includes the code for a PDO query of the database and checking of a password with php's password_hash function.  I will point out the code that is specifically relevant to your question:

Assuming that as you are building a login page, and wanting to send users to other parts of the site relevant to their status. I think the whole script is relevant. You can easily swap and change what happens as a result of the session variable values.

```
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //start the session before sending any other output
        session_start();
        require('dbconn.php');
    // checks if a session eid has been set, if so, send them to the usercp.
        if(isset($_SESSION['eid'])){ header("Location: usercp.php"); } else {

        try{
        //build a login page
        $loginpage ="<html><head><title>Portal Login</title></head><body>";
         $loginpage.="<div align=\"center\" id=\"box\">";
         $loginpage.="<table><tr><td><img src=\"images/login.jpg\" /></td></tr>";
         $loginpage.="<tr><td><div align=\"center\">";
         $loginpage.="<font face=\"Courier New, Courier, monospace\">Please enter your email<br />  address and password.</font><br />";
         $loginpage.="<br /><form action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\"login\" ><div align=\"right\">";
         $loginpage.="<font face=\"Courier New, Courier, monospace\">Email:</font><input type=\"text\" size=\"40\" name=\"email\" />";
         $loginpage.="<br /><br /><font face=\"Courier New, Courier, monospace\">Password:</font><input type=\"password\" size =\"40\" name=\"password\" />";
         $loginpage.="<br /></div><br /><input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\" />  ";
         $loginpage.="&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Login!\" />";
         $loginpage.="</form></div></td></tr></table></div></body></html>";  

        //checks if somebody is trying to login
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        //checks that the username and password have both been filled out if not, show the login page
            {   if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['password'])
               {
                   echo $loginpage;
               echo "Please enter your login details";
               } else {  //otherwise search the database for the email address
                        $db = NEW pdo($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
                        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = :email");
                        $check->bindParam(":email", $email);
                        $check->execute();
                       //unset the session variables
                        unset($_SESSION['eid']);
                        unset($_SESSION['email']);
                        unset($_SESSION['userlevel']);
                        unset($_SESSION['fname']);
                       //check if the password hash matches php's hash of the password
                        if(($row = $check->fetch()) && (password_verify($password,$row['password']))) {
                       // set the session variables
                        $_SESSION['eid'] = $row['eid'];   
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['userlevel'];
                        $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['fname'];
                        // if the user's userlevel is higher than 1 give them the option of the admin page
                        if($row['userlevel'] > "1")  { 
                            echo "<center><a href='usercp.php'><h1>User Panel</h1></a><br><br><a href='admin/admincp.php'><h1>Admin Panel</h1></a></center>";

                                } else {   //otherwise send them straight to the usercp
                                    header("Location: usercp.php");
                                }


                        } else {  //if the email is not found or password is incorrect, show the loginpage again
                                echo $loginpage;
                                            echo "Login details incorrect, please contact your manager.";

                        }

               }

            } else {  //if nobody has logged in already, or tried to log in just now, show the login page

                         echo $loginpage;

            }
        //pdo error reporting code
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
}

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: take a second look at this `if(!$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['password'])`

Comment: I think you are mixing the `MYSQI_` and `PDO` database extensions. They are not compatible or interchangable